# Apply function on large mts data set takes very long time

Tags: r, time-series

I want to calculate the Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI) by using the "SPEI" package. I have done this oftentimes before, also for larger data sets, without any problems except that sometimes it took quite a long time.
Now I need to do calculate it again with using a reference period that covers only a certain range of the values.

Here is some code for an reporducible example:

```
library(SPEI)

# create a big data frame
precip.df <- data.frame(replicate(222000, sample(0:30, 480, rep= TRUE)))
```

The dataframe is supposed to represent monthly precipitation data between 1980 and 2019 (40 years * 12 months = 480 rows) for 222000 grid cells (number of columns).

Now, since I need to use a reference period, the dataset must be converted to time series:

```
precip.df.ts <- ts(precip.df, start= c(1980,1), end= c(2019,12), frequency= 12)
```

This leads to a `Large mts` object in which every single value in the columns is assigned to a certain year and month.

Now the final step would be to calculate the SPI values by using a reference period (1981 - 2010). The result should be a dataframe with the same dimensions as `precip.df.ts`, so that every columns represent a SPI time series:

```
spi3.df <- spi(precip.df.ts, scale= 3, ref.start= c(1981,1), ref.end= c(2010,12))$fitted
```

The problem is that this step is taking ages, I stopped it after more than 12 hours when it was still not finished.
So I am looking for a way to accelerate this calculation process. I am open for any suggestions.

Anybody with a hint?

Comment: The package depends on `parallel`, I couldn't find any options for parallelization, though. Perhaps you could write the [authors](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/index.html).